# How to Move Rigidbody2D in a Curve

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and Rigidbodies and am able to move my Rigidbody2D in a straight line when using the `.AddForce()` command. I am also able to add a spin to the Rigidbody2D using the `.AddTorque()` command.

How would I be able to combine these (as well as different Rigidbody2D commands) to make the body follow the red and green lines shown in the image? Curve 1 the body comes out at an angle and is then released and Curve 2 comes out at a 0 degree angle and is released.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the curve in points, looking at the clisest one, rotating at it or adding force in the direction of the closes point will have your rigidbody move along the curve.

Comment: In my earlier attempts I have used a Bezier curve and made an arc and had the object follow that, I guess I should've specified earlier but the rigidbody needs to be able to collide and react to other rigidbodies

Comment: Thats why i tought of the solution to just divide the curve in points and add force in their direction  so you can still have the collision working